# Generating a textbox when user clicks on a gyphicon-plus

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

Is there a way of generating a textbox whenever a user clicks on a gyphicon-plus or would a regular button be more ideal? I'm trying to create a motto where when it pops up, the user can click on the gyphicon-plus button & it will generate a text box.

Thanks!

Comment: More information about that what you have accomplished so far would be great. Also information about the environment you are trying to embed that behavior in would be helpful: Webforms, MVC, Ajax etc. Right now your question is more like "Guess what I am doing and solve my problem".

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could just add a function in the controller to do this but it is considered best practice to use directives any time you are manipulating the DOM.

The directive definition:

```
app.directive('addInput', function($compile){ 
  return {
  restrict:'E',
  template:'Click symbol to add <span ng-click="addTextBox()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
  link: function(scope, element){
      scope.addTextBox = function () {
        var el = $compile('<input type="text">')( scope );
        element.parent().append( el );
      };
    }
  }
})
```

Then in your HTML

```
<add-input></add-input>
```

Comment: Why do you assume he's using angular?

Comment: Oh I thought I was in the angular tag section. Must've just been browsing javascript accidentally.